# Accessing var function within function in another file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 JS files - one with the functions I would like to access and the other that I'd like to call the function with.

```
(function($) {
    var Place = function() {
        var Location = function(id, duration, check) {
           //Should access this function
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to access it with:

```
Place.Location(markerId, 600);
```

But all I'm getting is that it's not defined. Simple issue but can't quite figure this one out.

As it's a jQuery plugin, maybe there's a way I can access it via another method?

```
$.fn.place = function(params) {
    var len = this.length;

    return this.each(function(index) {
        var me = $(this),
            key = 'place' + (len > 1 ? '-' + ++index : ''),
            instance = (new Place).init(me, params);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are defining `Location`, it is a private variable inside the function `Place`. If you want to access it as an attribute of `Place`, you should replace `var Location = ...` with `this.Location = ...`

Comment: Thanks but then `Location` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

It's going out of scope. Because you wrapped your Place object in `function($) {}`, now anything outside that wrapper will no longer have access to variables inside the wrapper. If $ stands for jQuery, it should be a global anyways and you can take the wrapper out.

Comment: Thanks David. So if I remove the outside wrapper would I then be able to use `Place.Location()`?

Comment: Yep! You can pass any parameter you need as well directly by doing `var Place = function(*arguments*) {};`

Comment: Thanks again. I've removed the outer function and then tried to access it with `Place.Location(*args*)` but it's still saying the same thing.

Comment: Are you initializing your `Place` object? Location will not be initialized unless you have something like `var myPlace = new Place();`, where the `Location` function will now be under `myPlace.Location()`. This is because `Place` will not run any of its inner code unless it is called, and `Place` will never be initialized.

Comment: Yep, I'm initializing it and still the same thing, "undefined...".

Comment: Try replacing `var Location` to `this.Location`. That way the reference to it is saved under Place.

Comment: That causes issues through the JS file as that function is called in several places. Have it as undefined in those other areas.

Comment: I think then you have to individually take a look at those references. Without knowing specifically how your code is organized, I can't help you much other than the instance you've presented.

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway. I'll look in to it now and if I sort it out, and the answer is like yours, I'll go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a combination of the other two answers.

1. You define `Place` as a variable in the (anonymous) function. It can't be used outside the scope of that function. (This function doesn't use jQuery, either, so the wrapper is unnecessary).
2. `Place` is a function. It executes code that sets local variable `Location` to a function, but doesn't export that function, so `Location()` is inaccessible outside the `Place` function.

You probably mean to make `Place` an object (instead of a function), and give it a `Location` method. Here's one way to write it:

```
var Place = {
    Location: function(id, duration, check) {
        // do something with id, duration, & check
    }
};

// execute
Place.Location(someId, someDuration, someCheck);
```

(It doesn't look like you've posted all your code, like the `Place.init()` method, but there are plenty of ways to write this so that it works correctly; this should solve your immediate problem.)